# e-mail gets rejected - bigfish.com error

Tags: email, unix

I am hosting several domains on a Unix server. I have several issues with others that intend to send e-mails hosted here but instead they receive this error:

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

name1@domain1.com
A problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this e-mail address. Try sending this message again. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

name2@domain1.com
A problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this e-mail address. Try sending this message again. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

The following organization rejected your message: domanin2.com.


Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: bigfish.com

name1@domain1.com
domanin2.com #<domanin2.com #5.0.0 smtp;554 mail server permanently rejected message (#5.3.0)> #SMTP#

name2@domain1.com
domanin2.com #<domanin2.com #5.0.0 smtp;554 mail server permanently rejected message (#5.3.0)> #SMTP#
```

any idea why this happens? The e-mails are valid and other persons / servers can successfully send e-mail to this one.

Comment: Perhaps you should speak to the admin at `bigfish.com` seeing as how their server is the (only?) one generating this message?

Comment: Actually bigfish.com is a domain of microsoft and from what I searched is a greylisting / blacklisting service, but I cannot understand exactly where is the glitch because simply going to that domain redirects here: http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/exchange-online-hosted-email.aspx

Comment: @voretaq7, Bigfish.com is Microsoft.  The use that for several email things but one of them is their cloud anti-spam service.

Comment: So this means that the sender is in the blacklisting of Microsoft or the destination?

Comment: @Zoredache I love when Microsoft tries to be cute.

Comment: It is difficult to tell given only the details you have provided.  What you really need is the full NDR including all the headers.

Comment: @voretaq7 Cute?  bigfish was the original domain name used by Frontbridge, which MS bought in turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something with greylisting, and its blacklist

our registers were:

```
Mar 13 18:03:03 mx greylisting filter[14855]: Starting greylisting filter...
Mar 13 18:03:03 mx greylisting filter[14855]: list type: black, from: ch1outboundpool.messaging.microsoft.com, match string: dsl|pool|broadband|hsd
Mar 13 18:03:03 mx qmail-queue-handlers[14854]: handlers_stderr: REJECT
Mar 13 18:03:03 mx qmail-queue-handlers[14854]: call_handlers: REJECT during call '/usr/local/psa/handlers/info/05-grey-oJSLrp/executable' handler
```

We fixed the blacklist, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

bigfish outgoing smtp servers are blacklisted, and they give a damm to that because they are BIG and the problem is not from "Microsoft" but from the other...

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a216.32.181.185

Many headache due to that. Customer even when i sent a report saying the problem is there's (bigfish), they answer, dude that Microsoft, the problem must be yours... not theirs

Answer (score 0):

You should check your domain for open relays (whether it will forward messages from any source to any destination, making it easy for spammers to abuse) and if possible sample your outgoing mail to see that you are not relaying spam.  Then, google for SMTP blacklists and contact the administrators of each to request delisting.  After that, and maybe waiting a week or so for convergence, you will find your deliverability improves generally.  You could also try talking to the listed administrative contact for bigfish and see if you can get them to remove you from their blacklist.

Comment: I have no open relays on the server.

Answer (score -1):

554 and 5.3.0 often mean that they think you are sending spam, basically your ip or domain's reputation is bad. Send an email to the email address below and include your server's IP address:

delist@bigfish.com

Comment: Remember - in SMTP **all 5XX** error-codes mean **only Permanent delivery failures and NOTHING MORE**. Forget your sick fantasies and RTFM RFCs

Comment: Then what exactly is the RFC error code for, "we've blacklisted you" ? Oh, that's right, there isn't one, so they have to send another error code when they drop the connection. Many/most codes have a meaning as defined in the RFC. Some examples are <quote>"no valid recipients" (554) reply in response to the DATA command </quote>;<quote>552 Requested mail action aborted: exceeded storage allocation</quote>;<quote>553 Requested action not taken: mailbox name not allowed</quote>.